# Jquery keyup Event with AJAX causing incorrect results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following Jquery code that listens to a user typing in a captcha and sends an ajax request on each keyup to see if the correct code has been typed:

```
$('#joinCaptchaTextBox').keyup(function() {
    $.get('scripts/ajax/script.php', {
        'join_captcha': '1',
        'captcha': $('#joinCaptchaTextBox').val()},         
        function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if(obj.ajaxResponse.status) {
                $('#joinCaptchaNotAcceptable').hide();
                $('#joinCaptchaAcceptable').show();
            }else{
                $('#joinCaptchaAcceptable').hide();
                $('#joinCaptchaNotAcceptable').show();
            }
    });
});
```

The PHP script on the other end just checks the session and replies:

```
if($siteCaptcha == $_SESSION['secretword']) {
  $this->captchaCompare = TRUE;
}else{
  $this->captchaCompare = FALSE;
}
```

This works fine 95% of the time but I'm finding sometimes it reports the captcha typed is incorrect even though its correct. I think this could be because when typed fast many requests are sent to the server and the order or requests coming back isn't the order sent and therefore (as only one will be correct) a prior one is recieved last and incorrect is displayed.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to ensure the last request sent is recieved last? Is there something I'm missing here. I can give more info.

thankyou

Comment: This will help as it will introduce a wait/delay https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch

Comment: This is a bad idea; it means a script only needs to send ~25*number of characters *at most* to brute-force your CAPTCHA. In other words, you WILL get spammed.

Comment: OK not so bad; I thought you were checking the text *so far*. But this is still very bad. There's a reason every CAPTCHA you've ever seen changes to a new one if you get it wrong. Computer vision is capable of narrowing down the possible letters, and if you allow multiple guesses (which this does) then brute force can be applied to the remaining possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a timeout so as to not send a request on every keyup when the user types fast:

```
$('#joinCaptchaTextBox').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer')  );
    $(this).data('timer', 
        setTimeout(function() {
            var data = {
                    join_captcha: '1',
                    captcha : $('#joinCaptchaTextBox').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url : 'scripts/ajax/script.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(result) {
                $('#joinCaptchaNotAcceptable').toggle(!result.ajaxResponse.status);
                $('#joinCaptchaAcceptable').toggle(result.ajaxResponse.status);
            });
        },500)
    );
});
```